# How to make two textboxes in a userform mutually exclusive

Tags: excel, vba

I have two textboxes in a userform.

I need that if the user has entered some number in one textbox and then places the cursor in the other textbox, the first text box data is deleted and vice versa.

I was able to lock the other textbox if one has data in it, as a workaround.

I tried to replicate the lock method for deleting the value, but it does not work.

```
Sub checkTB()

If ConversionForm.Controls("UnitFromEntry").Text <> "" Then
    ConversionForm.Controls("UnitToEntry").Locked = True
Else

    ConversionForm.Controls("UnitFromEntry").Locked = True
End If
End Sub
```

I call this sub in the before update event of the text box.

```
Private Sub UnitFromEntry_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Call checkTB
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into other events, like `GotFocus` and properties like `Enabled` - not sure `Locked` is what you need here, but there isn't really enough information in your question to give you a decent answer.

Comment: How to work with the GotFocus event. I do not seem to find it in the events list for the text box.

Comment: my bad... it's called `Enter` in Excel VBA... It should do the same thing tho

Comment: you were right, I was placing the code in the wrong event controller. After I put it in the enter event, it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: how do I accept your answer? I do not see the check symbol on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub UnitToEntry_Enter()
    UnitToEntry.Locked = False
    UnitFromEntry.Locked = True
    UnitFromEntry.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub UnitFromEntry_Enter()
    UnitFromEntry.Locked = False
    UnitToEntry.Locked = True
    UnitToEntry.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: actually I do not want to lock the text box, I want that if one text box has focus then the other one should not have any text. So it will check which one has the focus and delete any data, if it is there, in the other text box. Sorry if I created confusion by adding the code related to locking of the text box.

Comment: @jafri np remove all lines that assign the ***Locked*** value